# Problem accessing a piece of information while parsing XML in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

My code will go through my XML file and pluck out the TO, FROM, and SUBJECT which works great. The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to extract the ID attribute from the ELEMENT nodes. I need that to identify the filename that is holding the content of the email. Nothing I've tried seems to work. Ideally that ID would be added to `strQuery`.

Here is an example of the XML I'm working with:

[image: Screenshot of XML data.]

Here is my code:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" )
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mail Enable\Postoffices\ACS\MAILROOT\name\Inbox\_index.xml")

strQuery = "//ELEMENT/ (FROM | TO | SUBJECT)"
'strQuery = "ELEMENT"

Set colNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(strQuery)
For Each objNode In colNodes
    WScript.Echo objNode.NodeName & ": " & objNode.Text
Next
```

Comment: Please do not post **images** of text or code (or xml). Post the actual text formatted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `ID` attribute of the parent node:

```vb
WScript.Echo objNode.ParentNode.GetAttribute("ID")
```

Alternatively, select the `<ELEMENT>` nodes, get its `ID` attribute, then select the desired child nodes:

```vb
For Each objNode In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ELEMENT")
    WScript.Echo objNode.GetAttribute("ID")
    WScript.Echo objNode.SelectSingleNode("./FROM").Text
    WScript.Echo objNode.SelectSingleNode("./TO").Text
    ...
Next
```

---

As a side-note, `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is deprecated. Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` instead.

Comment: Ok thank you that got me over the hump. Now to filter the results based on user input.